# last reboot and who -b shows different results?

Tags: reboot, uptime

I am using the following 3 commands to check the latest time point when my computer is rebooted:

```
last reboot
who -b
uptime
```

The result for last reboot is:

```
wtmp begins Sat Oct  9 04:49:27 2021
```

The result for who -b is:

```
system boot  2018-01-11 20:52
```

The result for uptime is:

```
22:49:01 up 1372 days, ...
```

It seems that the result of uptime and who -b is consistent with each other, but inconsistent with that of last reboot.

I find this post [Uptime and who -b are showing different times when the system was last booted on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18413/uptime-and-who-b-are-showing-different-times-when-the-system-was-last-booted-on), but it said his uptime and who -b is inconsistent with each other, different from my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, all three commands use different sources of information by default.

`uptime` uses the information given by the kernel in `/proc/uptime`. The latter [contains two pieces of information](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html): the system’s uptime, including time spent suspended, and the time spent in the idle process. These values are accurate.

`who -b` uses the information stored in [`/var/run/utmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html). On current systems, this is really `/run/utmp`, and only has information for the current boot (`/run` is a `tmpfs` which loses its contents when the system is rebooted); but for the current boot, it is also accurate.

`last reboot` uses the information stored in `/var/log/wtmp`. The information stored there is also generally accurate, but the information you *need* might no longer be stored there: `wtmp` is rotated in many setups, typically monthly. This means that if the system’s current boot time is older than `wtmp`’s last rotation time, the information presented will be partial. In particular, `last reboot` ends up showing the last rotation time, not the system’s actual boot time. This is why `last` shows the time at which `wtmp` begins: that’s the time horizon for the information displayed by `last`.

When `wtmp` contains the last boot time, `last reboot` does show it:

```
$ last reboot | head -n 1
reboot   system boot  5.10.0-8-amd64   Mon Sep 13 15:56   still running
$ who -b
         system boot  2021-09-13 15:56
$ uptime
 09:11:03 up 31 days, 17:15, 13 users,  load average: 0.48, 0.34, 0.42
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems my last reboot does not reflect the reboot time, but the rotation time.

Comment: @alancc you can try using the old rotated files (e.g., `last -f /var/log/wtmp.1`) to see if earlier information is available.

Comment: @muru, that returns "no such file" which means the earlier files are not existing any more. But I find another file wtmp-20211009, after using that file, the restart time is bring to August 29.